# Convert text to image Immediately using ajax on key up event

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, image

I am working on stencil project i am trying to convert text to image.here i have text box on key up event i am getting the text whatever user entered in text box,after entering a text i am trying to convert that text into image on same page in div name imageprint.

In bellow snap shot you can seen that entered text in the text box continuously converting in the image.

[image: see example what i am looking for]

**Bellow is my code (index.php)**

In the code i am passing JavaScript variable to php code to convert the text to image but it's not working i am very new to ajax i f any body have any solution let me know.

```
<html>
  <head> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>-->
  <title>
  </title>
  </head>
  <body>
 <!-- <form name="FORM" method="get" action="">     -->
Line 1:
<input type="text" name="text1" id="textinput">
<script>  

var textinput = document.getElementById('textinput');
textinput.onkeyup = function() {
   alert(textinput.value);
      var test=  textinput.value;

  $.ajax({
       type: "GET", 

        url: "index.php",
       data: "cid=" +test ,      
        dataType: 'html', 
        success: function(data) {
           //  $("#textinput").html(data);   
      }
    });   
} 
    </script>   
<div id="imageprint">
<?php
  header("Content-type: image/png");
$cid=$_GET['cid'];
####################### BEGIN USER EDITS #######################
$imagewidth = 500;
$imageheight = 100;
$fontsize = "20";
$fontangle = "0";
$font = "ByzantineEmpire.ttf";
$text = $cid ;
$backgroundcolor = "003366";
$textcolor = "FFCC66";
######################## END USER EDITS ########################

### Convert HTML backgound color to RGB
if( eregi( "([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})", $backgroundcolor, $bgrgb ) )
{$bgred = hexdec( $bgrgb[1] );   $bggreen = hexdec( $bgrgb[2] );   $bgblue = hexdec( $bgrgb[3] );}

### Convert HTML text color to RGB
if( eregi( "([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})", $textcolor, $textrgb ) )
{$textred = hexdec( $textrgb[1] );   $textgreen = hexdec( $textrgb[2] );   $textblue = hexdec( $textrgb[3] );}

### Create image
$im = imagecreate( $imagewidth, $imageheight );

### Declare image's background color
$bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, $bgred,$bggreen,$bgblue);

### Declare image's text color
$fontcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, $textred,$textgreen,$textblue);

### Get exact dimensions of text string
$box = @imageTTFBbox($fontsize,$fontangle,$font,$text);

### Get width of text from dimensions
$textwidth = abs($box[4] - $box[0]);

### Get height of text from dimensions
$textheight = abs($box[5] - $box[1]);

### Get x-coordinate of centered text horizontally using length of the image and length of the text
$xcord = ($imagewidth/2)-($textwidth/2)-2;

### Get y-coordinate of centered text vertically using height of the image and height of the text
$ycord = ($imageheight/2)+($textheight/2);

### Declare completed image with colors, font, text, and text location
imagettftext ( $im, $fontsize, $fontangle, $xcord, $ycord, $fontcolor, $font, $text );

### Display completed image as PNG
$html=imagepng($im);


### Close the image
imagedestroy($im);

?>
</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

If i separate the logic in separate file `some.php` something like

```
$.ajax({
           type: "GET", 

            url: "some.php",
           data: "cid=" +test ,      
            dataType: 'html', 
            success: function(data) {
               //  $("#textinput").html(data);   
          }
        });
```

**Some.php like bellow**

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: image/png");
$cid=$_GET['cid'];
####################### BEGIN USER EDITS #######################
$imagewidth = 500;
$imageheight = 100;
$fontsize = "20";
$fontangle = "0";
$font = "ByzantineEmpire.ttf";
$text = $cid ;
$backgroundcolor = "003366";
$textcolor = "FFCC66";
######################## END USER EDITS ########################

### Convert HTML backgound color to RGB
if( eregi( "([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})", $backgroundcolor, $bgrgb ) )
{$bgred = hexdec( $bgrgb[1] );   $bggreen = hexdec( $bgrgb[2] );   $bgblue = hexdec( $bgrgb[3] );}

### Convert HTML text color to RGB
if( eregi( "([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})", $textcolor, $textrgb ) )
{$textred = hexdec( $textrgb[1] );   $textgreen = hexdec( $textrgb[2] );   $textblue = hexdec( $textrgb[3] );}

### Create image
$im = imagecreate( $imagewidth, $imageheight );

### Declare image's background color
$bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, $bgred,$bggreen,$bgblue);

### Declare image's text color
$fontcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, $textred,$textgreen,$textblue);

### Get exact dimensions of text string
$box = @imageTTFBbox($fontsize,$fontangle,$font,$text);

### Get width of text from dimensions
$textwidth = abs($box[4] - $box[0]);

### Get height of text from dimensions
$textheight = abs($box[5] - $box[1]);

### Get x-coordinate of centered text horizontally using length of the image and length of the text
$xcord = ($imagewidth/2)-($textwidth/2)-2;

### Get y-coordinate of centered text vertically using height of the image and height of the text
$ycord = ($imageheight/2)+($textheight/2);

### Declare completed image with colors, font, text, and text location
imagettftext ( $im, $fontsize, $fontangle, $xcord, $ycord, $fontcolor, $font, $text );

### Display completed image as PNG
$html=imagepng($im);


### Close the image
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

**Checkout the demo for separate logic file**

[Click here for demo](http://stencils.bluecoresyspvtltd.com/stackdemo/)

Getting the response from ajax like bellow snap.

[image: response from ajax]

Comment: success: function(data) is used when the request gets something back from where you call it, I think you need a fully qualified URI for the url (as in http://yoursite.com/index.php). I'd also separate this logic with the logic from outputting the image, so you call something like http://yoursite.com/image_generate.php from the index.php ajax

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @user3036342 i have tried with separate logic file check the demo link  http://stencils.bluecoresyspvtltd.com/stackdemo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have another idea without using AJAX for this. Basic JavaScript, `onkeyup` event, you need to change the `<img />` tag's `src` attribute. I don't understand the point of using AJAX here. It is better to have the basic attribute value changing script here instead of AJAX.

A minimal level of code would be:

```
<img class="stencil-main" id="stencil-main" />
<input type="text" name="stencil-text"
       onkeyup="document.getElementById('stencil-main').src='some.php?img='+this.value" />
```

I am still not sure of what's the use of AJAX here, but the above code does the same work. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: can you elaborate it.

Comment: yes you are right  there is no need to ajax great answer from me +1